# How to execute ipp-over-usb at startup?

Tags: linux, boot, services, sysvinit, devuan

I using a non-systemd distribution of Linux (sysvint) am using CUPS for printing. However, the `ipp-usb` program doesn't execute at startup by default. Somehow I suspect it is because I am not using systemd. What is the appropriate way to set it up to get it to run at startup? If it is utilizing a service, would it be possible to share the appropriate code snippet, or link to a beginner tutorial that will do what I need? I ask because it was surprisingly difficult to find an explanation by searching. The present installation is devuan, but it would be nice if it was beginner friendly and worked for more general non-systemd linux distributions.

Answer (score 1):

The [Debian package](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/amd64/ipp-usb/filelist) indeed includes a system-wide service configuration. It's generally the job of Devuan's package maintainers to make sure their package includes whatever kind of configuration is suitable for the distribution's init system (whether taken from the upstream source or written by the packager).

> and worked for more general non-systemd linux distributions.

One of the reasons for systemd's popularity is that before it took over, writing and enabling a startup service was anything *but* generic – a Debian-style "SysV" init.d script is not the same as a RedHat-style "SysV" rc.d script, with Arch's "BSD/SysV crossover" rc.d scripts being even further away.

Assuming Devuan has kept the original Debian sysvinit setup, you will need to find specifically a template for Debian-style init scripts, which are kept in `/etc/init.d` (either `/etc/init.d/chrony` or [this gist](https://gist.github.com/drmalex07/298ab26c06ecf401f66c) may be a good example to copy from), and enable the script using `update-rc.d`. The [Debian Wiki article](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts) might help.

Debian also has a [simplified framework](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/sysvinit-utils/init-d-script.5.en.html) for init.d scripts.